# Why does Ascorbic Acid on paper turn brown when heated?

Tags: oxidation-state

I am finding conflicting information about how ascorbic acid degrades and turns brown when used as "invisible ink" on paper and then heated.  Some say the heat accelerates the natural degradation process when it is exposed to air (oxidation?) and some say that the heat rearranges the molecules.  Can someone explain in some detail what is actually happening?  Does ascorbic acid turn brown when NOT on paper?  What is the chemical process involved?

Thanks.

Comment: "Invisible ink" works because of caramelisation - it has barely anything to do with vit. C

Comment: @Mithoron So this would be pyrolysis rather than oxidation of the cellulose, and the acid is not what turns brown.

Comment: @Karsten Yeah, acid's just a catalyst.

Answer (score 4):

While I did not find sources that directly address your question, what I read about durability of paper seems to say that the acidity of the ascorbic acid would weaken the paper, accelerating the aging process and making it more heat-sensitive.

In the classical "magic ink" experiment, the sender uses lemon juice to write an invisible message, and the recipient heats up the paper to visualize the message. The active ingredient in lemon juice magic ink is citric acid, although it also is a source of vitamin C a.k.a. ascorbic acid. (A lemon has grams of citric acid and only milligrams of ascorbic acid.)

Other acids like acetic acid (from vinegar) or lactic acid (from milk) also work.

The U.S. Library of Congress has a nice article on [preserving paper](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/care/deterioratebrochure.html) that mentions acid and heat treatment.